# Springdoc: Exclude custom global header parameter for certain endpoints

Tags: header, springdoc

If I create an OperationCustomizer that adds a new global custom header parameter to all endpoints, how do I go about adding an exclusion list for a smaller subset of non-applicable endpoints?

```
@Bean
    public OperationCustomizer customize() {
        return (operation, handlerMethod) -> operation.addParametersItem(
                new Parameter()
                        .in("header")
                        .required(true)
                        .schema(new StringSchema())
                        .description("Customer Header Parameter")
                        .name("custom-header-parameter"));
    }
```

Comment: mmateyak, your question seems to be answered :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use OpenApiCustomiser, which is called after all OperationCustomizer(s).

Here is a sample code that you can adapt:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser customerGlobalHeaderOpenApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().values().stream().flatMap(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().stream())
            .forEach(operation -> {
                        // remove the global header only for operationid = search
                        if ("search".equals(operation.getOperationId())) {
                            operation.getParameters().removeIf(parameter1 -> "custom-header-parameter".equals(parameter1.getName()));
                        }
                    }
            );
}
```